# Java Convert Negative float to byte array

Tags: java, sockets, floating-point, type-conversion, byte

I'm currently working on a 2D MMORPG.
So, now I'm tring to handle the coordinates, but I have a problem.
I need to convert negative float (coordinate) to bytes, send it to the server through socket, and then convert back to coordinate (float).
I'm stucked at this part.

Send to the server:

```
out.writeByte(packettype);
            out.writeFloat(x);
            out.writeFloat(y);
            out.flush();
```

Convert back:

```
            float x,y;
            byte[] xA = new byte[4];
            byte[] yA = new byte[4];
            for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
                xA[i-1] = (byte) b[i];
            }
            for(int i=5;i<9;i++){
                yA[i-5] = (byte) b[i];
            }


            x = ByteBuffer.wrap(xA).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getFloat();
            y = ByteBuffer.wrap(yA).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getFloat();
```

If my coordinates are under 0, I get values like this:

X---------Y

2,3964    3854642970624

2,3964    2857584033792

2,3964    4395458363392

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally you'd use a `ByteBuffer` or a `DataOutputSream` for this.

Comment: output (client side): `DataOutputStream.writeFloat()` input (server side): `DataInputStream.readFloat()` since Java 1.0 **Why** is this a problem?

Comment: @markspace As you can see, I tried with `ByteBuffer`, but it doesn't help.
And my "out" variable is a `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: Why aren't you using a `DataInputStream` to read in data you wrote using a `DataOutputStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Send to the server:

```
out.writeByte(packettype);
out.writeFloat(x);
out.writeFloat(y);
out.flush();
```

Receive from the client:

```
byte packettype = in.readByte();
float x = in,readFloat();
float y = in.readFloat();
```

... where `in` is a `DataInputStream`.